# How the consume can notify the JMS queue to hold the message

Tags: java, queue, jms

My scenario is, I listen a queue. If a message is posted, I will consume it and forward it to another app.

Is it possible that when finding the app　is down, I can notify the queue, in some way, to hold the message so that I don't get the message. Then when the app come back, I will notify the queue that i can process the message again.

It seems that the "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode doesn't help on this situation.

Help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about closing your JMS connection when your app is down and re-establishing it once your app is up ? Make sure the timeout for the messages in queue is set to "0" so that they would be persistent. You can look at the below to know about JMS persistence http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/DeliveryMode.html#PERSISTENT

Comment: @kalyan, thanks for your answer. it should work for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you have two possibilities:

1. just stop consuming the messages. In this case, the messages will stay in the queue until you resume processing.
2. Generate another queue as a back channel and send stop/start messages over this queue to the producer of the messages. This can also be regarded as an implementation of backpressure.

imho, 1. should be sufficient in most cases. 2. will be necessary, if the amount of messages generated leads to large resource (memory/disk) consumption that you want to avoid. you could still use a combination of the two, e.g. if the app is down for more than some time, you notify the producer.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solutions. Please note that #1, #2 are "manual", #3 is "real". The choice depends on your needs.

1. Check the application availability before consuming the message. This will work, but has a problem: what if the app becomes unavailable exactly at the moment when you are consuming the message?
2. Consume message, try to send it to your app. If the attempt fails, push the message back to the same queue. However be careful with this solution: if you push message to queue you consume it again immediately, try to send it to app that is probably still unavailable, push it to queue again etc.
3. The real solution is to use transactions. This is exactly what you need. If app is unavailable, throw exception. This will start the re-try mechanism automatically.

Comment: thx for your answer. But for my situation, stop listening the queue is the easiest way to implement. :)